# Отправить почту SMTP на с++

Tags: smtp

Клиента делаю на с++ VS 2015
Инициализацию с сервером упущу, сделаны 2 функции по приему и по отправке данных....

```
//получение сообщения от сервера после коннекта
priem();
/ приветствуем сервер
otpravka("HELO smtp.mail.ru\r\n");
priem();
// сообщаем отправителя
otpravka("MAIL FROM : <>\r\n");
priem();
// сообщаем получателя
otpravka("RCPT TO : eagl69@mail.ru\r\n");
priem();
```

**Вывод:**

```
Ожидание приема данных
принято байт: 34
220 smtp51.i.mail.ru ESMTP ready

Отправлено байт - 13
HELO smtp.mail.ru

Ожидание приема данных
принято байт: 16
250 smtp51.i.mail.ru

Отправлено байт - 10
MAIL FROM : <>

Ожидание приема данных
принято байт: e
250 2.0.0 OK

Отправлено байт - 1a
RCPT TO : eagl69@mail.ru

Ожидание приема данных
принято байт: 1a
500 unrecognized command
```

**500** - это Синтаксическая ошибка, команда не была распознана. В чём здесь ошибка?

Добавил кавычки <> Вот что получилось
Ожидание приема данных
принято байт:  34
220 smtp52.i.mail.ru ESMTP ready

Отправлено байт - 1a
HELO

Ожидание приема данных
принято байт:  16
250 smtp52.i.mail.ru

Отправлено байт - 21
MAIL FROM :

Ожидание приема данных
принято байт:  e
250 2.0.0 OK

Отправлено байт - 1b
RCPT TO :

Ожидание приема данных
принято байт:  2c
501 Syntactically invalid HELO argument(s)

Отправлено байт - 6
DATA

Ожидание приема данных
принято байт:  0

Comment: The second step in the procedure is the RCPT command.  This step of
   the procedure can be repeated any number of times.

      RCPT TO:<forward-path> [ SP <rcpt-parameters> ] <CRLF>
Из RFC: 
   The first or only argument to this command includes a forward-path
   (normally a mailbox and domain, **always surrounded by "<" and ">"
   brackets**) identifying one recipient. Может, поэтому...

Comment: @Harry: не всегда, зависит от MDA. Postfix в этом плане весьма дружелюбен, к примеру. 
Юрий Пикин: вообще, да, попробуйте email получателя поместить в угловые скобки.

Comment: Да и пробел после **TO** я бы тоже убрал.

Comment: Я тут пощупал telnet'ом - похоже, проблема в том, что этот конкретный сервер не принимает по smtp ничего левого (даже такое полачал: not local sender over smtp). Так что попробуйте потренироваться на каком-то сервере полояльнее :) Поставьте себе что-то простенькое локальное, и потестируйте, не выходя из машины...